# Why is an overload error occurring, even though everything is fine?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am developing my first application in reaction with TS and when I try to instantiate a prop in a react-select element the following error appears;

Failed to compile

```
C:/Users/Lucas/OneDrive/Desktop/projetos/ws-sds2/dsdeliver/front-web/src/Orders/OrderLocation.tsx
TypeScript error in C:/Users/Lucas/OneDrive/Desktop/projetos/ws-sds2/dsdeliver/front-web/src/Orders/OrderLocation.tsx(66,13):

No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Props<Place, false, GroupTypeBase<Place>> | Readonly<Props<Place, false, GroupTypeBase<Place>>>): Async<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '(inputValue: string, callback: (places: Place[]) => void) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '(inputValue: string, callback: (options: readonly (Place | GroupTypeBase<Place>)[]) => void) => void | Promise<readonly (Place | GroupTypeBase<Place>)[]>'.
      Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'void | Promise<readonly (Place | GroupTypeBase<Place>)[]>'.
        Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<readonly (Place | GroupTypeBase<Place>)[]>'.
          Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'readonly (Place | GroupTypeBase<Place>)[]'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: Props<Place, false, GroupTypeBase<Place>>, context: any): Async<Place, false, GroupTypeBase<Place>>', gave the following error.
    Type '(inputValue: string, callback: (places: Place[]) => void) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '(inputValue: string, callback: (options: readonly (Place | GroupTypeBase<Place>)[]) => void) => void | Promise<readonly (Place | GroupTypeBase<Place>)[]>'.  TS2769

    64 |             placeholder="Digite um endereço para entregar o pedido"
    65 |             className="filter"
  > 66 |             loadOptions={loadOptions}
       |             ^
    67 |             onChange={value => handleChangeSelect(value as Place)}
    68 |           />
    69 |         </div>
```

where am I assigning this prop

```
function OrderLocation({ onChangeLocation }: Props) {
  const [address, setAddress] = useState<Place>({
    position: initialPosition
  });

  const loadOptions = async (inputValue: string, callback: (places: Place[]) => void) => {
    const response = await fetchLocalMapBox(inputValue);

    const places = response.data.features.map((item: any) => {
      return ({
        label: item.place_name,
        value: item.place_name,
        position: {
          lat: item.center[1],
          lng: item.center[0]
        }
      });
    });


<AsyncSelect
            placeholder="Digite um endereço para entregar o pedido"
            className="filter"
            loadOptions={loadOptions}
            onChange={value => handleChangeSelect(value as Place)}
          />
```

Comment: If you have errors, please paste those errors. Don't use links to pictures.

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJ91Rm), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: It would also be helpful to see the type definitions for this component (OrderLocation), and what you are assigning your `loadOptions` variable to.

Answer (score 0):

`loadOptions` cannot return a promise, so we need remove the `async` keyword, change the code like below:

```js
  const loadOptions = (inputValue: string, callback: (places: Place[]) => void) => {
    const handleAsync = async() => {
      const response = await fetchLocalMapBox(inputValue);

      const places = response.data.features.map((item: any) => {
        return ({
          label: item.place_name,
          value: item.place_name,
          position: {
            lat: item.center[1],
            lng: item.center[0]
          }
        });
      }
      handleAsync()
    };
```